# Google cloud storage API: unable to open file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using this piece of code to look at the response status:

```
for i, status in enumerate(result.statuses):
        print('Status of processing line {} of the csv: {}'.format(
            i, status))
        # Check the status of reference image
        # `0` is the code for OK in google.rpc.Code.
        if status.code == 0:
            reference_image = result.reference_images[i]
            print(reference_image)
        else:
            print('Status code not OK: {}'.format(status.message))
```

And, I get this error message:

```
Processing operation name: projects/furniture-vs/locations/us-west1/operations/63a6b48c2c4ef9c0
Processing done.
Status of processing line 0 of the csv: code: 5
message: "Error opening file: gs://furniture-vsearch/dtbo160x90x75w5m1-hero-618173ee-high.jpeg."
```

***But we can see that the file is present in the location:***

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you show the lines where you attempt to open and access to your bucket?

Comment: Also, could you try running this gsutil command to set the GCS permission to public-read? `gsutil acl set public-read gs://furniture-vsearch/dtbo160x90x75w5m1-hero-618173ee-high.jpeg`

Comment: Can you share the API call that you perform? I have the feeling that you get only the metadata and not the content of the file